# Why is this coming back as Undefined?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have this for loop that is supposed to loop through an array of objects of members, get their ID, and remove a specific role from everyone in the array.

```
for (let x = 0; x < competition.length; x++) {
   message.guild.members.cache.get(competition[x].id).roles.remove('775547730901729330')
}
```

I use the same line of code for another command that works perfectly. Never had an issue. For some reason in this command, it's telling me roles is undefined which means it's not getting the ID, correct? I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working.

The array is set up like this:

```
[
 {
   "name": "QuazArxx",
   "id": "IDNumber"
 }
]
```

It's not just me on the list. The list can change depending on who joins or leaves. I'm just trying to iterate through the array to remove the same role from everyone in the list.

Comment: To clarify, you’re stating that you’re using `competition[x].object.userId` to access the array you shared in the body of your question? Where did you get the key values `object` and `userId` from?

Comment: You seem to be using `competition[x].object.userId` to get the id, but the data is formatted as `competition[x].id`?

Comment: Meant to adjust that. I have another property called object which stores "message.member" so I tried to use that instead and forgot to change it back

Comment: What intents do you have? I believe you need Guild Members Intent and fetch all the users to cache them.

Comment: I don’t have it fetching all users since I never needed it before v13. I have the intents on the site turned on and I have the Guild Member intent added to my index file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem through a series of tests to find who it was getting stuck on. It turns out the person it was stuck on left the Discord server so it couldn't find them in the Guild Members and came back as undefined. I will be adding a way to catch that so it ignores that person.